# Возврат ответа с сервера AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarDirection;

loadit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(a:MouseEvent) {
// Нулим значения загрузки
bar.setProgress(0, 100);
perlabel.text = "0%";

function progressHandler(aa:ProgressEvent):void {
    var pers:Number = Math.ceil(Number(aa.bytesLoaded / (aa.bytesTotal / 100)));
    perlabel.text = pers.toString()+"%";
    bar.setProgress(pers, 100);
}
function completeHandler(ba:Event):void {
    bar.visible = false;
    perlabel.visible = false;
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", ba);
}
// Загрузка и окна
var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Изображения (*.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif)", "*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif");
var fileWindow:FileReference = new FileReference();
var fileUpload:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
fileUpload.url = "http://[SITE]/technical/attachments/download.php";
fileWindow.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function(ca:Event) {
    var fileLoader:FileReference = FileReference(ca.target);
    fileLoader.upload(fileUpload);
});
fileWindow.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, function(a:Event) {
    //trace("Cancel loading!");
});
fileWindow.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
fileWindow.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
fileWindow.browse([fileFilter]);
    });
```

В ответе ba.target.data равна null,

```
({type:"complete", bubbles:false, cancelable:false, target:{type:".png", data:null, name:"blacklordtrans.png", creationDate:(new Date(1352890430442)), creator:null, modificationDate:(new Date(1352890431778)), size:312412}, currentTarget:{type:".png", data:null, name:"blacklordtrans.png", creationDate:(new Date(1352890430442)), creator:null, modificationDate:(new Date(1352890431778)), size:312412}, eventPhase:2})
```

при том что сервер должен был вернуть к примеру GOOD, может проблема в кодировке или в чём-то ещё?

Comment: А можно привести кусок серверной части? В которой идет обработка...